# Does telekinesis do Bashing or Lethal?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, damage

I'm trying to figure out what type of damage a direct physical assault with telekinesis would result in.  (From NWoD)

From pg. 212 of World of Darkness:

> Alternately, the ghost can make a direct attack on a victim,
>   using its raw power to inflict cuts, bruises and bites on the
>   victim’s body. Treat this as a normal attack with a -3 modifier.

That's not very specific.  Cuts, bruises, and bites sounds like bashing damage to me, though.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 13):

**It's bashing.**

On the same page, in an earlier paragraph, the power of Telekinesis is described as letting a ghost do "basically anything a mortal could do with his hands." Since hand-to-hand fighting does bashing damage, that's what you get. It's only if you use the power to manipulate an object, like swinging an ax, that you might get access to lethal.